# Scaling canvas while maintaining the center

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using `SurfaceHolder` and `ScaleGestureDetector` for my scaling to work.In between the `SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas()` and `surfaceHolder.unLockCanvasAndPost(canvas)` I perform scaling operation.

```
canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, scalePointX,scalePointY);
```

In the onScaleMethod, I perform the following

```
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 35f));
            scalePointX=(detector.getFocusX());
            scalePointY=(detector.getFocusY());
            Log.i("Zoom",mScaleFactor+""); 
         return true; 
}
```

But the canvas does not scale in the center between the two fingers.How should i adjust the values of scalePointX and scalePointY for the code to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see this is quite an old question but let's have it answered at least.

The problem in your code is that focus coordinates are basically the pixel coordinate which was clicked on your view. It's the one you would normally get from a motion event. In other words - it's not the the coordinate on your image (or whatever you're scaling).

Here is my solution:

I don't use scale point but rather translate the whole canvas respectively. I hold translation coordinates in units at 1.0 scale (no scaling). If you want to use scale center instead, you would only have to change starting coordinates to the center instead of top left corner as I do. Here is part of my onScale function (I also update scale factor and add some more restrictions but this is the only part that has to do with maintaining the center):

```
float sf = mScaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();
float x = (mScaleGestureDetector.getFocusX() / mScaleFactor) * (1 - sf);
float y = (mScaleGestureDetector.getFocusY() / mScaleFactor) * (1 - sf);

mTranslateX += x;
mTranslateY += y;
```

What I basically do is convert focus point coordinates to unscaled units (the division part) and then calculate how much of each coordinate has gone out of screen (or into the screen if it's negative).